# Set background colour to blank in Bootstrap Customizer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap v3.1.1
I want to remove the background definition of the panel header in a customised bootstrap build. If i just blank the field in the customizer it defaults the built back to the default colour. I know i could overwrite this in my own stylesheet but wondered if there was anyway to   blank this in customizer.

Comment: Could you put an RGBA value? rgba(255,255,255, 0);

Comment: Hi Paulie, the problem is that the css generated is very selector specific. So what ever i do will override anything I do in my stylesheet which is a bit more OO. I could put a selector specific def in my css or even use important but would rather not. I want a range of panels so i may go down the route of using contextual alternatives bur was just curious in general if blanking the fields could be achieved in the customizer.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the response Paulie